# Android app crashes at first launch but works well after restart when using Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, crash

I use Parse.com library in my Android app. When installing the app on a device, the app crashes at first launch when using Parse for the first time. If I re-launch the app (just after, not changing anything) it works great.

Parse is initialized in the onCreate method of my application and it is called (tested with debugger).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bla.bla.bla.activities.PreselectionActivity_}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
```

How I initialize Parse (in CustomApplication.java which extends android.app.Application :

```
Parse.initialize(this, app_id, client_id);
```

The line which throws the error:

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

This line is supposed to return null because at this point the user is not logged in.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: What is ParseUser? Share some code.

Comment: ParseUser is a class which is included in Parse, it represents a user

Comment: where do you call `ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` You shouldn't call it immeadiately after the `initialize` as that method is async and needs time to finish.

Comment: *`Parse.initialize` is async method* ? seriously? where it it stated?, if it is async, where it has callback parameter?

Comment: @Selvin I do completely agree with you.

Comment: @RobVoisey How can I be notified that initialized has completed ? getCurrentUser is called when a button is clicked on the home screen so it is called after my first activity is completely loaded

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it in a while and seemed to remember it being async, though as you mentioned, can't find it documented anywhere. If your getCurrentUser is not called immeadiately after then it doesn't matter if it is or isn't anyway.

Comment: On a side note, the logcat did suggest that it wasn't initalised. You can google the exception and thats what lead me to the conclusion it hadn't finished initalizing.

Comment: Do you need to call `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` before Initialize?

Comment: Yes that was my first guess, but as I couldn't find a callback method and waiting a bit before pressing the button calling the getCurrentUser method doesn't fix the problem I suppose it is not a question of initialization completeness. And yes, I call enableLocalDatastore before init